# How to sort a date (YYMMDD) and validate it?

Tags: c++, validation

I'm creating a project which requires a date in YYMMDD format so I'm looking for a way that I can use to validate it's a "date" and how can I sort the dates? Any help is appreciated.

Data type should be int.

Comment: Please give us more information e.g. what data type is the date? is it a string with no spaces?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode It's `int`.

Comment: YYMMDD is sortable as a string if all your dates are 2000 or later.

Comment: Are you able to use C++11?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Nope, unfortunately.

Comment: @MarkRansom There are dates before 2000 too..

Comment: @user2699298: Can there be future dates? If so, how do you determine the valid date range? Otherwise, I assume your dates can only be in the range 1914-2013 (and in a few weeks, it'll be 1915-2014) (i.e. in the range `(present day - 100 years, present day]`).

Comment: Well, In case there is a date in the future (assuming it's 2014), there should be an error.

Comment: Also, *what have you tried*? I could write this, but I'm more inclined to "teach a man to fish" rather than just "give hime a fish," to be cliche.

Comment: @Cornstalks I've written 100+ lines for my program so far, but it's irrelevant to this code, because it's the last part I have unfinished.. you don't have to write the whole code, just give me the instructions how to proceed and I'll try it on my own, if I can't finish it, then I'll ask for more help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/date_time.html 
should do all of that and then some

`std::string ds("2002/1/25");
date d(from_string(ds));`

Comment: It should be `int` and has length 6 (YYMMDD).

Comment: can you provide some code? if it's int than sorting should be easy?

Comment: 'should' be easy.. but I'm having problems. the code isn't done, but what i'm trying to achieve is basically i have a .dat file with dates and I want to sort them.

Comment: can you show a couple dates? you could use a bit mask

Comment: `951022
130525
130625`

Comment: Is this an inflexible external requirement?  You have a Y2K-style problem with this scheme.  For instance, is 500101 January 1st, 1950 or January 1st, 2050?

Comment: It's YYMMDD as specified in the first post. YearMonthDay

Comment: Hm.. reading your post, you're correct, it's a huge mistake in the exercise, but fortunately there are no dates like that, it starts from 80s and goes to today's date at highest.

Comment: I've revised my answer to do sort / parse.  my cpp skills are rusty. but it works
Not sure how tell SO to format this code correctly, here's a paste binhttp://pastebin.com/Lzkze2PE

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving a date in a format that is not guaranteed to work, store the input YYMMDD as a string. Grab the first two characters from the string (this should be trivial, strings are arrays of chars and arrays have direct-access). Make sure that these two characters may be converted into an integer number between 00 and 99 inclusive. If it's not (for example, if it's letters or symbols) return false. Do the same for months which can only be between 01 and 12. Use streams to convert the characters into numbers. Do the same for days, a cap of 31 and a floor of 01 should be enforced.

If you want to confirm such a date could actually be valid based on a calendar, a slightly modified algorithm should be applied. (For example, leap-years would have an extra day on February whereas it should be illegal in non-leap years).

Finally in order to sort them, define a custom comparator for a class that should be created called Date. Then store Date objects in a collection (your pick) and apply the sort algorithm, sending it the custom comparator. The sort should be similar to that of a radix sort where significant digits would be the years.

If any of this sounds obfuscated, let me know and I will fill in details.

Comment: Well, I do understand everything you said except the last sentence about the sorting. Do you mind if you explain that a little bit more or some kind of psuedo / c++ code?

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I should have thought what I said out a little better. Basically contain each date in buckets based on their years. So looking only at year, sort them within each bucket (say 84). Then looking at each chunk per year make monthly buckets. For each monthly bucket, finally sort them by their day fields. I recommend reading up on radix sorts. It's not hard to find a C++ implementation online.

Answer (score 1):

If passed as a simple integer you can use std::to_string then parse that string to check every 2 characters.

Example:

```
bool check_year(int year){
    ... check year for roll-over e.g. 99 to 00 ...
    ... if too low or high, false ...
}

bool check_day(int month, int day){
    ... check day based on month ...
    ... if too high, false ...
}

bool is_date_good(int date)
{
    std::string yolo = std::to_string(date);

    int check;

    check = stoi(yolo.substr(0, 2));
    if(!check_year(check))
        return false;

    check = stoi(yolo.substr(2, 2));
    if(check > max_month) // should be 12
        return false

    int month = check;
    check = stoi(yolo.substr(4, 2));

    if(!check_day(month, day))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Note, though, that the OP said he isn't using C++11.

Comment: That's for the validation part, which I think I understand well now. But the problem is sorting.

Comment: With a function like the one I wrote above (maybe without the c++11 ;) ) you can sort it using your own or one of the STL algoritms very easily.

The nicest way would probably be to store it in a `std::vector<int>` and using `std::sort` to sort the list into ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like everyone else is using strings. If you have an `int` with the format `YYMMDD` and it's guaranteed to always be in that format, you don't really need strings. Here's how I would go about getting the individual numbers out of it:

```
struct date { int year; int month; int day; };

date getDate(int yymmdd) {
    date d;
    d.day = yymmdd % 100;
    yymmdd /= 100;
    d.month = yymmdd % 100;
    yymmdd /= 100;
    d.year = yymmdd;
    return d;
}
```

Now, validating this is a whole other issue. Dates are complicated and you'll probably miss something unless you have a test suite to run against, so it's definitely recommended to use `boost.date` or something similar. Otherwise, you'll have to check if the day is `<=` 28, 29, 30, or 31 depending on what month it is, and if that year is a leap year (which is not just every 4 years). But it's definitely recommended to just go with a proven library.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have dates since 1980, a cheap and dirty way to sort these would be to store the date as an integer of the format SSMMDD, where SS is, rather than the year, the years since 1980.  Then they'll be in numeric order and you can sort them without a custom comparitor.  When reading the date:

```
if (YY >= 80) {
    SS -= 80;
} else {
    SS += 20;
}
```

Of course, you'll have to apply the reverse transform to the date before outputting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
include      // std::cout
include     // std::sort
include        // std::vector
```

int getYear(int date) {
  int year =  (date / 10000);

return (year < 20) ? 2000+year : year;

}
int getMonth(int date) {

int month = (date / 100) % 100;
  return (date /100) % 100;

}
int getDay(int date) { 
  int d2 =  (date /10) % 10;
  int d1 =  (date /100) % 10;

return d2*10+d1;

}
bool myfunction (int i,int j) {

if  (getYear(i) > getYear(j)) return true;
  if  (getYear(i) == getYear(j) && getMonth(i) > getMonth(j)) return true;
  if  (getYear(i) == getYear(j) && getMonth(i) == getMonth(j) && getDay(i) > getDay(j)) return true;
  return false;
}

int main () {
    int myints[] = {130525,951022 , 130624, 121212};

`std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+4);              
           std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myfunction); 

       std::cout <<  "Year: " << getYear(130525);
       std::cout <<  "Month:" << getMonth(130525);
       std::cout <<  "Day:" << getDay(130525);

       std::cout << std::endl <<std::endl;
       std::cout <<  "Year: " << getYear(951022);
       std::cout <<  "Month:" << getMonth(951022);
       std::cout <<  "Day:" << getDay(951022);

       std::cout << std::endl;

                   std::cout << "myvector contains:";
                     for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
                         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
                           std::cout << '\n';

                             return 0;
                             }`

Made a boo boo, this is correct updated pastebin http://pastebin.com/yvBNrcTU